# Max limit of oozie workflows

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-workflow

Does anyone have any idea on what's the maximum limit of oozie workflows that can execute in parallel?

I'm running 35 workflows in parallel (or that's what oozie UI mentions that they all got started in parallel). All the subworkflows perform ingestion of files from local to HDFS & do some validation checks henceforth on the metadata of file. Simple as that.

However, I see some subworkflows get failed during execution; the step in which they fail tries to put the files into HDFS location, i.e., the process wasn't able to execute `hdfs dfs -put` command. However, when I rerun these subworkflows they run successfully.

Not sure what caused them to execute and fail on `hdfs dfs -put`.

Any clues/suggestions on what could be happening?

Comment: I would be really surprised if the `hdfs` commands failed without spitting out an error stack. So what do you see in the YARN logs??

Comment: BTW the biggest user of Oozie, by far, is Yahoo! -- and indeed they developed that tool to manage tens of thousands of *massive* jobs per day and per cluster. So Oozie can be scaled beyond your wildest dreams.The limit is rather the resources available in YARN and HDFS...

Answer (score 0):

First limitation does not depends on Oozie, but on resources available in YARN to execute Oozie actions as each action is executed in one map. But this limit will not fail your workflow: they will just wait for resources.

The major limit we've faced, leading to troubles, was on the **callable queue** of oozie services. Sometime, on heavy loads created by plenty of coordinator submitting plenty of worklow, Oozie was loosing more time in processing its internal callable queue than running workflows :/
Check oozie.service.CallableQueueService settings for informations about this.